# Collections and drafts, or non-outputting elements

Tags: jekyll

I'm using a Jekyll collections to render a group of pages using:

```
collections:
    mycoll:
        output: true
        permalink: /:collection/:path/
```

And a set of files:

```
_mycoll/
    el1.md
    el2.md
    el3.md
    ...
```

But I need to avoid the generation of some pages of this collection, just like post drafts.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under jekyll 2.x, use `_config.yml` exclude array :

```
exclude:
 - _mycoll/el2.md
```

With Jekyll 3.x, use post/collection item `published` front matter variable

```
---
title: toto
published: false
---
content
```

Comment: I've update the jekyll version of the project (now is `3.1.3`) and while the first way (_exclude_ array) works nicely, the second (_published_ front matter) doesn't.

Comment: This is supposed to work. Check for typo. `published: false` or even  `published: no`

Comment: I've tried, but no luck. Seems that [I'm not the only affected](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/2956).

Comment: This issue was talking about the 2.x not 3.x. Any repository url ?

Comment: I've found the problem: there's a version mismatch between the global jekyll gem the local that I'm using with bundler. Both solutions works as expected. Thank you.